# What is a 0-size file "Icon?" in a directory?

Tags: macos

I just noticed in my `~/Copy` directory there is a file named `Icon?` that is 0 byte.

The file is only visible by a `ls` command.

I'm just curious what for this file exists, does anyone know about it?

Comment: Did you have a custom icon for this directory previously?

Comment: This folder is made by `Copy` app, so maybe that was the reason. Thanks!

Comment: The data fork of `Icon\r` files is empty because the image data is stored in the resource fork. Run `cat Icon$'\r'/..namedfork/rsrc` or `xattr -l Icon$'\r'` to see the contents of the resource fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually named "Icon\r" (you can verify this with ls in Terminal) and indicates a custom icon for the directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an empty file. Nothing more.

Since the `~/Copy` is not a standard directory, it is hard to say why is it there or why it was created.

Comment: Then, can I ask why this file is created?

Comment: `~/Copy` is not a standard directory, so hard to say.